# How to create a loop with two variables, where one variable only changes after every nth loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program where I have two lists & one dictionary:

```
dict = {'fruit1' : 'apple', 'fruit2' :'banana', 'fruit3':'cherry' ....and so on} 
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e'....]
list2 = ['fruit1', 'fruit2','fruit3'....]
```

I have a program which looks like this. [This is not right at all, but it helps represent what I'm trying to get as the result].

```
for obj1 in list1:
    for obj_2 in list2:
        print(obj1)
        print(obj_2)
        print(dict[obj_2])
```

My need is to loop this in a way where `obj_2` changes every nth loop, but `obj_1` changes every loop. How can I achieve this?
So my result would look like(considering nth loop is 3rd loop):

```
a
fruit1
apple
b
fruit1
apple
c
fruit1
apple
d
fruit2
banana
e
fruit2
banana
f
fruit2
banana
g
fruit3
cherry
.
.
.
```

Comment: "How can I achieve this?" - please be more specific what "this" actually is = please provide a *complete* sample input (not "and so on") and expected output (I am not really sure what you meant)

Comment: Swap order of the two `for` loops.

Comment: I've made some changes based on Jan Stránský's comment.
Thanks for pointing out where my question lacked clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `enumerate` function and the modulo operator

```
for idx, obj1 in enumerate(list1):
    obj2 = list2[idx % n]
    # more code
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is hat you want, but you can just change the order of your two loops.
If you do something like this :

```
for obj2 in list2:
    for obj1 in list1:
        print(obj1)
        print(obj2)
        print(dict[obj2])
```

you will have 'obj1' changing every loop, but 'obj2' changing only after the end of the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal, you simply need to switch your loop statements. To demonstrate see this simple example:

```py
n = 3
for i in range(2):
    print(f"{i}")
    for j in range(n):
        print(f"\t{j}")
```

This program is written so that `i` changes once for every n changes of `j`. This will output something like:

```
0
    0
    1
    2
1
    0
    1
    2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. dict = {key1:value1, key2:value2, ... }
   *use ":" instead of "="
2. does this solve it for you?

   ```
    for obj_2 in list2:
       for obj1 in list1:
          print(obj1)
          print(obj_2)
          print(dict[obj_2])
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, had a brain fart while typing.
Fixed the dictionary syntax, but that's not what I was looking for.